# How do I fix this I want to solve it using a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

```
num = 0
number = int (input("what is your number"))

word = input("what is your word")

while num<number:

  num+1

  print(word)
```

**I want it to print word as many times as number but for some reason it keeps on printing it for infinity I also want to stick to a while loop doing so **

Answer (score 3):

You need to increment the counter and override its last value for the while loop condition to work. In your case, `num` value is never incremented and loop continues `infite`

How to increment the counter? See below

```
num = num+1
```

or

```
num+=1
```